# Send/Create an SQL request for Marketing Cloud with SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, sql, automationstudio, custom-activity

I'm working on a custom activity for JourneyBuilder in nodeJs and I need to make an SQL request like in automation studio to make a process easier. I found [the package node-saleforce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-salesforce) where you can do SQL but it seems impossible to reach dataExtensions of marketing cloud :

```
var records = [];
conn.query("SELECT Id, Name FROM Account", function(err, result) {
if (err) { return console.error(err); }
console.log("total : " + result.totalSize);
console.log("fetched : " + result.records.length);
});
```

Is there a SOAP or REST call to make this possible pls ? If you have an other method to make this easier, I would be glad to see it.  Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to do the same, I found [this SOAP call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_query_activity.htm) that enable us to create SQL query with a XML file like this :

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <UsernameToken>
                <Username>USERNAME_GOES_HERE</Username>
                <Password>PASSWORD_GOES_HERE</Password>
            </UsernameToken>
        </Security>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Options>
            </Options>
            <Objects xsi:type="QueryDefinition">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true">
                </PartnerKey>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true">
                </ObjectID>
                <CustomerKey>New Query Key</CustomerKey>
                <Name>New Query</Name>
                <Description>Some Description</Description>
                <QueryText>Select EMAIL_ADDRESS as EMAIL from [Example DE]</QueryText>
                <TargetType>DE</TargetType>
                <DataExtensionTarget>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true">
                    </PartnerKey>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true">
                    </ObjectID>
                    <CustomerKey>FIRST SEND</CustomerKey>
                    <Name>First Send</Name>
                </DataExtensionTarget>
                <TargetUpdateType>Overwrite</TargetUpdateType>
            </Objects>
        </CreateRequest>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I then used the [package 'easy-soap-request'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-soap-request) that enable to send SOAP request like this :

```
const soapRequest = require('easy-soap-request');

// example data
const url = 'https://webservice.s10.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx';
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
  'soapAction': 'Create'
};
const xml = fs.readFileSync('backend/CreateQueryDefinition.xml', 'utf-8');
console.log('XML : '+xml);
// usage of module
(async () => {
  const { response } = await soapRequest(url, headers, xml);
  const { body, statusCode } = response;
  console.log(body);
  console.log(statusCode);
})();
```